# sqoop import from SQL Server with windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, ldap, windows-authentication, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to import a table from Microsoft SQL Server 11.0.5058 through Sqoop (which is a service on Hortonwork Data Platform) into HDFS. Given the user i have, has only windows authentication (LDAP) on SQL Server.

Tried few approaches 
 1. Kept the sqljdbc4.jar in sqoop shared library and used import command.
 2. Downloaded sqljdbc_auth.dll and kept it in java library and tried running import command.

But no luck.

Comment: I have the same problem. It looks like this is not supported: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/52137/sqlserver-sqoop-import-integrated-security-kerbero.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/apps/lib/java/jdbc/jtds-1.3.1-patched/jtds-1.3.1.jar \
sqoop import --table XXXXX --connect "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://XXXX:1433;useNTLMv2=true;domain=XXXX;databaseName=XXXXXX" \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --username XXXX -P \
--verbose

Answer (score 0):

Here are some Sqoop commands using jTDS to access and import the data from Microsoft SQL Server using windows authentication.

First download jtds driver and place it in your local then export it.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:<path>jtds-1.3.1.jar

sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;database=<db_name>;domain=<domain>;useNTLMv2=true" \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager \
--driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver \
--username <user_name> --password-alias \
--query "SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE \$CONDITIONS" -m 1\
--target-dir "<HDFS_PATH>" \
```